# How to work with Jenkins Git Publisher

Tags: android, jenkins

I am new to jenkins through constant search in google found as jenkins git publisher would allow to tag or branch a git repo in jenkins can anyone tell me the method on how to work with it. As I would like to tag my Android project through jenkins git publisher.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I use the Git Publisher to Push the tags. I only do when the Build is Succeeded as shown in the below image. I use the Tag to push as `${BUILD_TAG}` which is an environmental variable, `(String of jenkins-${JOB_NAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}. Convenient to put into a resource file, a jar file, etc for easier identification)` I have checked both Create new tag and Update new tag because if the tag is not present it will create a new tag or otherwise it will update the existing tag.

[image]